# Convert ss.xxx to mm.ss.xxx - Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

How do you convert ss.xxx to mm:ss:xxx in Powerbi query editor?

For example, my data is coming in like 229.19, i can convert this to 0.00:03:49.190000 using #duration.

```
#duration(0,0,0,[Cumulative_Time])
```

However i would like a solution that doesn't include days and hours, and rounds to nearest 3 decimals.

I am trying to achieve "03:49.190"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite a difficult answer, as there is no ready format to solve the issue about fraction of second, however my result will depend on how much `fraction of demical` is, but rather fixed a decimal value for it, accept the answer if helping :)

Two type of method:

**A)** Pure M code:

Formula as following:

```
let   
minduration = Duration.Minutes(#duration(0,0,0,[Column1])),
minutes = if minduration < 10 then 
"0" & Number.ToText(minduration) else  
Number.ToText(minduration),

secduration = Duration.Seconds(#duration(0,0,0,[Column1])),
sec = if secduration < 10 then 
"0" & Number.ToText(secduration) else   
Number.ToText(secduration),

result = minutes & ":" & sec

in  
result
```

The result:

[image]

**B)** Mix method using `dax` and `m code`

First, I will create formula in `M` to extract seconds and fraction:

```
Duration.Seconds([Minute Sec])
```

Second, I will use dax `Format` function to extract `minute` part and `concatenate` for both minute and sec frac

```
Expected Output = FORMAT('Table'[Minute Sec],"nn") & ":" & 'Table'[Minute Frac]
```

Here is the result, I also include another example with second fraction with 3 decimal by referring to `Hour Sec`

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks Kin. One issue i am trying to sort out though. Method A) drops the leading 0's in the seconds position. e.g. 02:03.52 will be 02:3.52. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Ya, i thought about this issue before, to solve it is same as how I address `minutes`, you can add `if` function when the `sec is lower 10` then add 0 in front of it, give it a try if cannot I will help you.

Comment: Hi Kin, if you'd be so kind.. im having issues with the formula..

Comment: I have amended the answer, take a look to solve your sec issue :)